# Final state after dispatching action is empty while testing redux-mock-store

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk, redux-mock-store

I'm using [redux-mock-store](http://arnaudbenard.com/redux-mock-store/) for testing my redux actions. However, I want to test my actions and the store in which they're getting set. My code goes something like this:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
const mockStore = configureStore([thunk])
const store = mockStore({ ...state })
console.log(store.getState()) // => { ...state }
store.dispatch(someAction())
console.log(store.getActions()) // => [ someAction() ] The action does show up here!
console.log(store.getState()) // => { ...state } But this is the same unchanged state as above
```

But my finalState is `empty`, I understand that no reducer is listening my action and the state is not getting updated. But I want to test my state with actions at one place. Is there any way to integrate that or there are some other npm module which provides that?

**Edit:**

I want to test my `store` and `actions` at one place. Is there or is there not a way to do that? Should I or should I not do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "at one place"? With `redux-mock-store`, you are testing that actions are being dispatched (very useful when working with async actions). On the other place, you can test the logic in your reducers. This way, all your app logic and flow will be tested.

Comment: @Héctor https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store/issues/71 After this discussion, I understood that it is not possible with `redux-mock-store` but intuitively, I felt it would've been better if I could check my reducer and actions at one place. I'm a newbie in writing test cases and as per business scenarios, I want to do that. Is there any other way?

Comment: Of course, you can use tools like Mocha or Jasmine. Forget react/redux here. You just want to test reducers logic, and that's just javascript. Given an action and a state, execute your reducer and check that new state is what you're expecting.

Comment: @Héctor Thanks. I should test my reducer stand-alone and `redux-mock-store` should be used when I'm using middleware for my actions. Closing the question

Comment: That's it! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

From the doc of [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store):

> Please note that this library is designed to test the action-related logic, not the reducer-related one. In other words, it does not update the Redux store. If you want a complex test combining actions and reducers together, take a look at other libraries (e.g., [redux-actions-assertions](https://github.com/redux-things/redux-actions-assertions)). Refer to issue [#71](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store/issues/71)
>  for more details.